# responsive justified menubar

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

I am trying to create a justified menubar so that the company logo is on the right side and the links are on the left. It needs to also be responsive so we can view it on mobile devices properly.

The first problem is the logo and menu items do not inline-block properly. 
 The second problem is the responsive element. I am trying to use the precentages correctly but i think im missing something? the inner div may be styled wrong..

Check out the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5Kbuq/

Here is the HTML element for the menu bar:

```
  <div class="subMenu" >    
     <h1> Site Name </h1>
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a> 
        <a href="#" id="s1" class="subNavBtn">About</a>
        <a href="#" id="s2" class="subNavBtn">Team</a>
        <a href="#" id="s3" class="subNavBtn">Work</a>
        <a href="#" id="s4" class="subNavBtn">Clients</a>
        <a href="#" id="Contact" class="ContactBtn">Contact</a>
    </div>          
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the menubar:

```
.subMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    height: 55px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(31, 50, 63, 0.25);

}

.subMenu .inner {
    padding:0;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.subNavBtn {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 12%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.end {
    margin: 0;
}

.ContactBtn {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 12%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any responsive code (media queries)... Might wanna look at using a grid or framework like twitter bootstrap

Comment: That positioning wont really give you that responsive feel.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/5Kbuq/2/ How big are you looking to make this picture?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast yes! the menu will stretch 100% width. The text and menu items need to be placed in the same line as well

Comment: So did I do exactly what you were looking for? Try adding a photo in as well.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast not exactly. Yes the bar works responsively but the logo and menu items are not on the same line

Comment: hello, maybe you should look at something like display;flex; justify-content:space-between or something alike : http://jsfiddle.net/5Kbuq/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people prefer to do their menu bars using lists.It is a nice practise and i recommend you to try it.Not to mean you are doing it wrong.

When it comes to responsiveness you can use something like this

```
body
{
   width: 100%;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-pack: center;
}
#page
{
max-width: 1500px;
margin: 20px 20px;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; /*responsive layout*/
   -webkit-box-flex: 1; /*1=flexible, 0=fixed*/
   background-color:   #f2f2eb;

}
```

with the webkit attribute you will get an automatic responsive page.
If you want to set the pixels that your site will transform to a mobile 
form, you have to use  what  Travis mentioned above or a preprocessor 
like sass when you can store in variables the desired height and width values.

About the logo try to make another div.Think of it like a puzzle.Sometimes drawing it on the paper might help you.